# CSRF token is not valid on symfony with API fetch

Tags: php, json, symfony, fetch

I try to fetch some data for my form using symfony but I have a problem with with the CSRF token.
this is my controller :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="index", methods={"GET, POST"})
 */
public function index(Request $request, CountryRepository $countryRepository, SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
{
    $cost = new Costs();
    $form = $this->createForm(CostsType::class, $cost);
    

    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
        
        $form->submit(json_decode($request->request->get('costs'), true));
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            //     $cost->setCompany($this->getUser()->getCompany());
            //     $cost->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());
                
            // $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            // // $cost->setDevise($cost->getCountry()->getDevise());
            // $entityManager->persist($cost);
            // $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Frais bien ajouté !'); 

            $response = new Response();
            $response->setContent(json_encode([
                'data' => 123,
            ]));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            return $response ;
        }
        
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(json_encode([
            'flash' => [
                'message' => "Une erreur est survenue !",
                'color' => 'danger'
            ],
            'data' => $serializer->serialize($form, 'yaml'),
            'request' => $serializer->serialize($request->getContent(), 'json'),
        ]));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response ;            
    }

    return $this->render('app/index.html.twig', [
        'cost' => $cost,
        'form' => $form->createView(),            
    ]);
}
```

this is my script with fetch, the error is the token is invalid :

```
/**
 * Helper function for POSTing data as JSON with fetch.
 *
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {string} options.url - URL to POST data to
 * @param {FormData} options.formData - `FormData` instance
 * @return {Object} - Response body from URL that was POSTed to
 */
async function postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData }) {
    const plainFormData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
    const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(plainFormData);

    const fetchOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: formDataJsonString,
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);

    if (!response.ok) {
        const errorMessage = await response.text();
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
    }

    return response.json();
}

/**
 * Event handler for a form submit event.
 *
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event
 *
 * @param {SubmitEvent} event
 */
async function handleFormSubmit(event) {

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#C9C9C9";
    event.preventDefault();

    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const url = form.action;

    try {
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        const responseData = await postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData });

        console.log({ responseData });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
}

const exampleForm = document.getElementById("formtopost");
exampleForm.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit)
</script>
```

on my template I have a basic form with the input hidden and the CSRF token.

but on my console I get this message :

```
Object { responseData: {…} }
​
responseData: Object { flash: {…}, data: "{ title: 'Validation Failed', type: 'https://symfony.com/errors/form', code: null, errors: [{ message: 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', cause: null }], children: { amount: { errors: {  } }, localAmount: { errors: {  } }, description: { errors: {  } }, devise: { errors: {  } }, createdAt: { errors: {  } }, costType: { errors: {  } }, country: { errors: {  } } } }", request: "\"{\\\"costs[country]\\\":\\\"5\\\",\\\"costs[devise]\\\":\\\"6\\\",\\\"costs[createdAt]\\\":\\\"2021-12-30\\\",\\\"costs[amount]\\\":\\\"12\\\",\\\"costs[localAmount]\\\":\\\"1.25\\\",\\\"costs[description]\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"costs[costType]\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"costs[_token]\\\":\\\"e6VFf4tQyNZnTL2UTYbLdaLZv0GCR43MRJh0W4kDyMk\\\"}\"" }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
ofinterne:248:11
```

thank's in advance for your helping

Comment: Why did you put this line `$form->submit(json_decode($request->request->get('costs'), true));` instead of `$form->handleRequest($request);` ?

Comment: An API is usually stateless. You probably want to avoid using anything that requires a session when you are in an API-context. This includes CSRF-Tokens and also using flash messages as you do in your controller. I can only guess, but I assume the request to your API in your JS-code is missing the header needed to evaluate the CSRF-token in your PHP-form.

Comment: HI, thank's for your reply. Also no is it not an API, i would send my forms with fetch and have no page loading. I have a user login with session.